# Nuxt.js - Is it appropriate to use the "Generate" property with a large amount of users?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

ok so I'm starting to use Nuxt in spa mode and I can see that dynamic pages work differently so I was searching and I found that I can use the [generate property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#routes)
to generate the dynamic pages when I start the production, but is it ok to use it if my API has too many users?? or is there a better way to create the dynamic pages??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on whether or not your production site will be static or server-side rendered.

`nuxt generate` is used for target: static (bundles the site as plain, SEO-friendly html pages)

`nuxt build` is used for target: server with either `ssr:` set to true or false. This bundles the site as either a server side rendered site or a single page application (SPA) with exclusively client-side navigation.

Good summary here: https://kontent.ai/blog/demystify-nuxt-target-mode-and-ssr-properties

I don't see any big problems in scaling a Nuxt application. But obviously involving server rendering will put some more strain on your server than a SPA or static jamstack-site with plain, prebuilt html pages.

If you don't need the SEO, then I would go for the SPA option with `ssr: false`. Super fast and requires minimal server resources on your end after the site has loaded on the client machine.

Comment: hey, that is perfect! I need to know, sorry that I got used to working only with `ssr: true` and  I'm planning to do my production site static, and that's why I'm having this question because I would like to know if there is another way to add the dynamic pages while I'm using `ssr: false` & `target: static`

Comment: `target: static` and `ssr: false` is not possible together. `ssr: true` is the default and is mandatory for static target mode. Your static site will behave like a static site even though ssr is true, it's just confusing wording from Nuxt. You will NOT need a server even if ssr is true. You just need a CDN that serves static html etc. instead of bundling everything together as a SPA app with client-side navigation. It's only if you add `target: server` you'll actually need a server, which will require some more resources on your end than target static.

Comment: That said, if you explain your motivation for asking information about "dynamic pages" etc. it will be easier to understand what you're looking for and how to help you.

Comment: @anatolhiman Could you elaborate on "target: static and ssr: false is not possible together"? It seems to work for me. In fact, the nuxt.config.js created with "yarn create nuxt-app [app-name]" and selecting "Rendering mode: Single Page App" and "Deployment target: Static (Static/Jamstack hosting)" contains exactly "target: static" and "ssr: false" together. Thanks.

Comment: @cjs1978 I quoted the article linked above: "With the ssr: 'false' option, there is no server-side rendering (only client-side navigation), and the whole app runs as a single page application. This mode is not available in combination with the target: 'static' option." I mentioned Nuxt's confusing wording: `ssr` isn't at all relevant for static sites, it doesn't matter if `ssr` is `true` or `false`. `ssr` only comes into play with `target: server` as far as I understand.

Comment: @anatolhiman You are right, I had misread your comment. Apologies. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @anatolhiman you are very misinformed and that quoted article is also wrong. `target: "static"` and `ssr: false` is a valid combination to achieve full client-side rendering.